# Spring Boot: Cannot map id field [Reup]

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am having a strange difficult problem. I write API to receive an object from MongoDB database using MongoRepository. But the nested id fields are null in the returned data.

It is quite strange that when I tried to edit '_id' instead of 'id' in the database it worked properly.

This is sample data taken from the database

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e57fcdbe7dd406f374bbf59"),
    "thumbnail" : ObjectId("5e6f5504e0729747af9d0d80"),
    "tags" : [ 
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("5f3f1edd4e1bd312a6f3adb9"),
            "category" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : ObjectId("5f4626844e1bd312a6f3adf3"),
                    "name" : [ 
                        {
                            "languageId" : 1,
                            "name" : "otra"
                        },
                        {
                            "languageId" : 2,
                            "name" : "other"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "name" : [ 
                {
                    "languageId" : 1,
                    "name" : "Mornitoring Station"
                }, 
                {
                    "languageId" : 2,
                    "name" : "Estación de monitoreo"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "media" : [ 
        ObjectId("5e5776de88242f7ee06cd92a"), 
        ObjectId("5e5776de88242f7ee06cd92a")
    ],
    "url" : "url"
}
```

Here is my code:

```
//Article class
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "article")
public class Article {
    
    @Id
    @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
    private ObjectId id;
 
    @Field(value = "thumbnail")
    @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
    private ObjectId thumbnail;

    @Field(value = "media")
    private List<ObjectId> media;
    
    @Field(value = "tags")
    private List<Tag> tags;
    
    @Field(value = "url")
    private String url;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    @Field(value = "createdDate")
    private Date createdDate = new Date();
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    @Field(value = "updatedDate")
    private Date updatedDate;

}
```

```
//Tag class
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Tag {
    
    @Field(value = "id")
    private ObjectId id;
    
    @Field(value = "name")
    private List<TagName> name;
    
    @Field(value = "category")
    private List<TagCategory> category;
}
```

This is the code I use to get data

```
Article article= articleRepository.findById(new ObjectId("5e57fcdbe7dd406f374bbf59")).orElse(null);
System.out.println(place1);
```

response data

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e57fcdbe7dd406f374bbf59"),
    "thumbnail" : ObjectId("5e6f5504e0729747af9d0d80"),
    "tags" : [ 
        {
            "id" : null, //The problem here
            "category" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : null, //The problem here
                    "name" : [ 
                        {
                            "languageId" : 2,
                            "name" : "otra"
                        },
                        {
                            "languageId" : 1,
                            "name" : "other"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "name" : [ 
                {
                    "languageId" : 1,
                    "name" : "Mornitoring Station"
                }, 
                {
                    "languageId" : 2,
                    "name" : "Estación de monitoreo"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "media" : [ 
        ObjectId("5e5776de88242f7ee06cd92a"), 
        ObjectId("5e5776de88242f7ee06cd92a")
    ],
    "url" : "url"
}
```

As you've seen. all fields have data except nested id fields (Tag Id & Category Id)

I have tried many ways but still cannot. Could you explain this to me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized the fix is to change import annotation @Field to import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;

Answer (score 1):

Try Removing @Field on Id field & add @Id there

Before:-

```
public class Tag {    
    @Field(value = "id")
    private ObjectId id;
```

After:-

```
public class Tag {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
```

Comment: I have tried it but still it doesn't work

Comment: @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class) you mentioned this as well ?

Comment: I also tried it (@JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)). Do not understand why so? This is the first time I encountered this problem in MongoDB